# Alternate formulation of h(P,T)?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

I'm using the following handbook *"Engineering and Chemical Thermodynamics 2nd edition"* by Koretsky. In the book they have an alternate formulation for *h(P,T)* though it was never explained how they got it ([source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3HrJ.jpg), equation 5.43).

I'm trying to prove:
$$dh=(c_p-{\beta}vP)dT + vdP$$
with $\beta$ the volumetric thermal expansion coefficient. I keep ending up with:
$$dh=Tds+vdP$$
$$dh=T(\frac{c_p}{T}dT-{\beta}vdP)+vdP$$
$$dh=c_pdT + (v-{\beta}vT)dP$$

How do you get the $-{\beta}vPdT$ term in the first equation?

Comment: Is it because $({{\partial}h}/{{\partial}T})_p = ({{\partial}u}/{{\partial}T})_p $ and $({{\partial}u}/{{\partial}T})_p = c_p - {\beta}vP$?

Comment: Your derivation is correct, of course.  There is no way that the equation you are trying to prove is correct, because it doesn't  deliver dh=CpdT at constant pressure.

Comment: It uses unusually small letters for H, S and V.

Comment: @Poutnik: in the book the use of uncapitalized letters are for intensive units, so unit of H is [kJ] while for h it's [kJ/mol]

Comment: @ChetMiller yeah, I tried to write it for an ideal gas so
$${\beta}=(1/v)({\partial}v/{\partial}T)_P =(1/v)(R/P)=1/T$$
Then, the first equation for an ideal gas would become:
$$dh=(c_p-R)dT+vdP{\ce{->}}???{\ce{->}}dh=c_pdT$$

Comment: dh is not equal to CvdT

Comment: It would be nice if you could confirm that the equation comes from a reputable textbook. The result might be due to some constraint which you have not mentioned.

Comment: This is from the aforementioned book on page 287: https://imgur.com/a/hhvTgII. Specifically equation (5.43). Equation (5.44) is also slightly amiss, as I think the Helmholtz free energy is volume dependent for IG (but that's a different question altogether).

Comment: In the provided source, the metioned equations (5.7) etc. are just the fundamental relations for dh, da, dg - e.g. dh=TdS + vdP.

Comment: The complete derivation shown in the image confirms that they messed it up. Expression 5.43 is not correct. You are welcome to post an answer.

Comment: Ok, if you are interested in bringing your own answer back to life perhaps the question needs to be edited too, and then the correct derivation which you performed can be moved to the answer, and elaborated upon. What might be useful to other visitors is to see that someone spotted this error in the textbook, and has posted a correction. If this is too much of a hassle then you can leave it alone, but I or someone else might take the liberty of performing these edits.

Comment: This is my first post on StackExchange, so I'm not entirely sure how to do this properly. If you or one of the mods could do it/show an example I'll know what to do for next time. Sorry for the trouble!